# Can EXIF image data be displayed on page using JSSOR?

Tags: javascript, image, tags, exif, jssor

Can JSSOR slider extract EXIF data from an image to be displayed on webpage?  More specifically, can the "title" of the image be extracted to be displayed under the the image?

This would be useful if you are dealing with hundreds or thousands of images, rather than adding an individualized additional tag per image.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [jQuery-fileExif](https://github.com/sanisoft/jQuery-fileExif) plugin to extract EXIF data, using the `exifAll` method to retrieve all EXIF tags (UserComment would be the most common EXIF tag) and add this data as the caption. Once you get the desired dats, you can use jQuery to append the caption HTML. Something along these lines:

```
$('ImageID').after('<div u="caption">HERE GOES THE CAPTION TEXT</div>');
```

Once you do that, you initialize the JSSOR slider.

Comment: Exactly. You can extract data by yourself and then append after image programmatically, and then initialize jssor slider.